# How I can extend a class that use a mixin to another class that are using mixin in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mixins, extends, flutter-freezed

I have a class that has a mixin generated through `freezed`.
I have another class that has a mixin generated through `freezed`.
I want to extend the second class, but I receive a type error because the mixin methods have differences.

**Example**:

```
class A with _$A {
  const factory A.initial() = _Initial;
}

class B with _$B {
  const factory B.final() = _Final;
}
```

**I want:**

```
class B extends A with _$B, _$A {  
  const factory B.final() = _Final;  
}
```

and then I should be able to use:

```
B.initial()
```

Comment: 1. Can you provide the exact error message? 2. Could you perhaps provide a simple, reproducible example that doesn't use `freezed`? 3. `class B extends A with _$B, _$A` doesn't make sense since `A` in your example already includes `_$A`.

Comment: Looks like you don't want class B extends A with _$B, _$A but you want class B extends A with _$B as class A is defined as already having the mixin _$A